# Taskrelation record issues when outlook to salesforce

Tags: apex

I am trying to associate an email in outlook to  an opportunity in salesforce.
I could do this successfully.But i do have a trigger on task ,after insert trigger,
When i debug this trigger i can see there are no taskrelation record created for this opportunity.

This is an issue because i am querying this taskrelation object in my trigger and doing some other logic.Since at the point of trigger run,
task relation object doesn't have my records my logic never gets executed
.But at some point it does get created because when i check into database ,by querying in dev.console after the code has been executed i can see task relation records there.

What is happening here.When exactly is taskrelationrecords getting created?

Answer (score 1):

Tasks are the parent of TaskRelation; the relationship can't exist before the task does. You'll need a future method to see the relations after the task trigger ends and the relations are created. I'd recommend the new Queueable interface so that you can retry the person in case the relations are not yet available.

Comment: Was considering future method, Queueable seems like a better choice.  But can you be sure that task will always have TaskRelations, so you don't requeue forever?  Safe to use the presence of the default TaskRelation (for whoid) as proxy for existence of all TaskRelations?  or better to just timeout after x retries?

Comment: @JasonClark I wrote this a while ago. I'm pretty sure retry isn't necessary as long as it's a single-contact event. I don't ever have a chance to use this object, but I'll see if I can come up with a definitive answer.